# What is the jQuery equivalent of dojo.create()?

Tags: jquery, dom, dojo

In Dojo, it is fairly easy to create DOM nodes without manually typing HTML tags and attributes. This is done with `dojo.create()`.

What is the equivalent in jQuery?

Comment: you can use $(selector).html() and $(selector).append() to simulate dojo.create() behavior in jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the signature of `dojo.create()`;

```
$('<input />', {
    name: 'foo',
    value: 'bar',
    id: 'fish'
});
```

For more info, see [the documentation for `jQuery(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)